# Java MOOC Exercise 80 Dice (Need help on explanation)

Tags: java

What is the difference between the two codes below? They produce the same randomized results I required in the output window but TMC does not accept it as solution.

### Solution accepted by TMC

```
    return this.random.nextInt(numberOfSides) + 1;
```

### Solution I came up with:

```
    return this.random.nextInt(numberOfSides + 1);
```

Do the codes above produce different result?

Comment: The second case can output zero.

Comment: In addition to @jonrsharpe, here is the javadoc for clearification: Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence

Comment: Thank you I studied and did some tweaks to code and experiment now I understood it.